# I want to retrieve a person phone number using Active directory

Tags: vb.net

When I try to get the phone number of a person from Active Directory, all the properties are loaded but except mail nothing is returned. Can someone please help out in how to retrieve the phone number with some changes in the below code? In `myrelustpropcollection.propertynames` only 2 is the count ADSPATH and mail. No other property is loaded.

```
Public Function GetPhoneByName(ByVal Name As String) As String
    Dim srch As DirectorySearcher
    Dim results As SearchResultCollection = Nothing
    Dim phone As Integer
    srch = New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry())
    srch.Filter = "(mailnickname=" + Name + ")"

    srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homephone")
    srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
    srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile")
    srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber")

    Try
        results = srch.FindAll()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    For Each result In results
        Dim myKey As String
        Dim myResultPropCollection As ResultPropertyCollection

        myResultPropCollection = result.Properties

        For Each myKey In myResultPropCollection.PropertyNames
            Dim tab1 As String = "    "
            Dim myCollection As Object
            Select Case myKey
                Case "mobile" ' Telephone Number
                    For Each myCollection In myResultPropCollection(myKey)
                        phone = myCollection.toint
                    Next myCollection
            End Select
        Next myKey
    Next
    Return phone
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me and the code is more concise:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.Collections

Public Function GetPhoneByName(Name As String) As String

    Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainName")
    Dim q As New UserPrincipal(ctx)
    q.DisplayName = Name
    Dim s As PrincipalSearcher = New PrincipalSearcher(q)

    Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = s.GetUnderlyingSearcher
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Clear()
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homephone")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber")

    For Each dsResult As SearchResult In ds.FindAll()
        For Each itm As DictionaryEntry In dsResult.Properties
            Select Case itm.Key
                Case "mobile"
                    Return itm.Value(0)
            End Select
        Next
    Next

    Return "Not found"

End Function
```

The following code will return all values available for the user from the active directory:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices

Module AdTest

    Sub Main()
        GetPhoneByName("Persons Display Name")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetPhoneByName(ByVal Name As String)
        Dim srch As New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry())
        srch.Filter = "(displayname=" + Name + ")"

        For Each result As SearchResult In srch.FindAll()
            For Each key As DictionaryEntry In result.Properties
                For Each keyVal In result.Properties(key.Key)
                    Try
                        Console.WriteLine(key.Key + ": " + keyVal)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        'value of keyVal could not convert to string (probably byte array)
                    End Try
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Nick thanks for the code. Can you please let me know why my code is not working and not able to get the value for the property

Comment: Hmm, did you change 'DomainName' to the name of your domain? Or do you mean my code works for you and yours does not?

Comment: I changeed the domain name to my domain name . but the code didnt work for me

Comment: Are you sure the person you are searching for has a mobile number assigned? you can check that on their contact card easily in outlook. If they don't, then you wont even get an entry in the list.

Comment: The only property which gets loaded is ADSPATH

Comment: Check my edit above, the second code block should return everything - can you try running that in a console app and see what you get?